Lashon Hara in the workplace - colleague speaks behind my back to the manager to blame me
Case :  Lashon Hara in the workplace - how to deal with it?
Hypothetical situation:
I and my teammate forgot to write a report for the manager. The teammate spoke to the manager the next morning and put the blame solely on me. A third colleague, who was an innocent bystander during the talk between the manager and my teammate, told me what had happended.
My guess is that ideally I should first talk to my teammate and ask her why she had done so, then she should apologize to me and go with me to the manager to speak about how to remedy the situation with the report.
What would be the best resolution of the problem?

I'm very sorry you have to deal with a situation like this. This is going to sound terribly pedantic, but lashon hara only happens when something is true. If the person tells lies, it's "Motzi Shem Rah"

לשון הרע and מוציא שם רע are extremely nuanced. There are a thousand details and a million potential mistakes, and a billion ways to misjudge a situation. This is for your Rav, not for the internet.

Social interactions are far too complex for halachah to cover every single permutation. It will tell you what is permitted and what is forbidden, but it can't tell you the best way to deal with the millions of scenarios that arise every day around the world.
You would have to supply far more detail for someone to advise you how to manage your situation, and even if you do manage to extract good and useful advice from the internet it would be more psychology than Judaism, I think.
Yes, maligning you as you described would indeed be Lashon Hara on your colleagues part, but there's no guarantee that pointing this out will bring you any closer to resolving your problem.

So basically, this question doesn't belong here?

@Chani I'm afraid so. This is for Reddit, not Mi Yodea.

It is a hard situation because a priori you do not know what your co-worker spoke to the manager about and whether your innocent bystander is actually telling the truth. Typically, problems like this one happen at the workplace, but we go to work to do work. The best way to address situation is to try to find out how the report can be produced in the shortest time possible and you certainly need to speak to the manager together with your co-worker about that. Alternatively, if the report is no longer needed you may discuss how to avoid forgetting the assigned tasks by using electronic calendar reminders, sticky notes, and other available tools - by being factual on the task, rather than by trying to give mussar to your teammates.
If you want to sharpen your skills about halachic problems to avoid, you may review any of the sources available such as "The Laws of Interpersonal Relationships" by R. Ehrman.
